# Resize an image using jQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a jQuery UI slider to resize an image proportionnally, at first uploaded an image an then you pass to the resizeing part and it work great so far. The only issue here is as soon is I position the range slider the image get small the it original width!! Here's my code :

```
//resize
var orginalWidth = $("#image").width();

$("#infoSlider").text(orginalWidth + ', 100%');

$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    step: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var fraction = (1 + ui.value / 100),
            newWidth = orginalWidth * fraction;

        $("#infoSlider").text('width :' + newWidth + ', Proportion :' + Math.floor(fraction * 100) + '%');

        $("#image").width(newWidth);
    }
});

// UPloded
$(function () {
            $(":file").change(function () {
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                }
            });
        });

        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
            $("#slider").removeAttr("style")
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

<div id="slider"></div>
<span id="infoSlider"></span>

<div class="target">
    <img id="image" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <input type='file' />
</div>
```

How I can fix this please! Much appreciated 
And here's a demo to to this issue : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/1/)
The issue : [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the loaded image's size in the variable once it is loaded.

Add this:

```
orginalWidth = $("#image").width();
```

To your function:

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $("#slider").removeAttr("style")
    $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    orginalWidth = $("#image").width(); // store the loaded image size
};
```

Check the values of fraction, width and proportion.

**When you change your slider to reduce, this is how it looks:**

[image]

**When you change back your slider, notice that the image is back to its original size**:

[image]

**When you increase your slide, notice that the values increase and so does image**:

[image]

---

## Edit:

The problem appears when you use the slider before selecting an image and also when you select a new image. This is because, the width of the `img` tag itself is changed and no matter how large an image you select, it will fit itself in the new dimensions of the `img` tag.

## Solution:

Use dynamically added `img` tags. Every time you select a new image, you remove the earlier `img` element and add a new `img` element. Assign the `src` of the new tag to the selected image. This way effectively the image is reset on every select.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/5/***

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var $newImg = $("<img>");                        // create a new img element
    $("#slider").removeAttr("style")
    $("#slider").slider('value', 0);                 // reset the slider
    $("#image").remove();                            // remove the existing img element
    $newImg.attr("id", "image");                     // add id to the new element
    $newImg.attr('src', e.target.result);            // assign src to new element
    $("#tgt").append($newImg);                       // add new element to DOM inside target div
    originalWidth = $("#image").width();             // now get the new width
    $("#infoSlider").text(originalWidth + ', 100%'); // reset the slider text
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please provide a demo ? Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3350731: You already have a fiddle with you. Just add that line in that function and see. Do you really want me to do that? Anyways, here: http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/2/

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work !! http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/2/show/ bcause for some reason it doens't worked if you waited a little

Comment: @user3350731: Why do you think its not working? Check the fraction and newwidth. Its coming up correct. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/3/

Comment: I think at first it initiated `orginalWidth ` with `72` since the img doens't exist yet !Even when it reload it stills the same !

Comment: Ok. (1) Goto http://placehold.it/128x128 (2) Download the image you get on your desktop (3) Upload this image to your fiddle (4) Check the fraction and width as you move your slider (5) Compare those values to 128 and you will see that it works correctly. Check the width when the proportion is 100%, the width should be 128.

Comment: I'm very Sorry but still ! :(

Comment: @user3350731: I have added screenshots to the answer to help understand better.

Comment: @user3350731: I don't see that problem in the fiddle I posted for you. I have added one more screenshot to show the increased size.

Comment: You have to wait until the slider shows then try it : http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/3/show/

Comment: @user3350731: Ok now I got it. Just give me a few minutes.

Comment: @user3350731: Check this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XQSLk/5/. I am updating the answer in a few minutes.